# Find $dy/dx$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have recently posted about solving a much easier problem using the theorem in question. Now, I decided to try and tackle a much more tricky problem. Namely:

> $$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_{\sin(x)}^{2x}\cos(t) dt$$ Find
>   $\frac{df}{dx}$

This is my solution: 
1. Rewrite this integral as a sum of two more-easily-computable ones:
$$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sin(x)}^0 \cos(t) dt + \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{2x}\cos(t)dt$$
2. Evaluate the first integral: 
$$f'(\sin(x)) = \cos(x) \frac {df}{d\sin(x)}$$
$$\int_{\sin(x)}^0 \cos(t) dt = \cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))$$
3. Evaluate the second integral:
$$\int_0^{2x}\cos(t)dt = 2\cos(2x)$$
4. Find the derivative:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))+ 2\cos(2x) \right)= \dots$$
The computation of this derivative is not the kernel of my problem and so I can skip it here. 
Do you think that my method / solution is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done every thing right except for $$ \frac {d}{dx} \int_{sin(x)}^0 \cos(t) dt = \cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))$$ where you missed a negative sign.

The correct answer should be   $$\frac {d}{dx} \int_{sin(x)}^0 \cos(t) dt = -\cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))$$

Comment: Is this because of this fact that when we apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the term containing the variable has to be the upper bound?

Comment: @Aemilius Perfect! It is exactly because of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

your integral is given by $$\sin(2x)-\sin(\sin(x))$$ and the first derivative is 
$$2 \cos (2 x)-\cos (x) \cos (\sin (x))$$

Comment: You simply computed this integral - the problem is required to be solved by the fundamental theorem.